# Disabled Input's Label not being assigned for attribute in Jquery

Tags: jquery, .net

I have created this function to add an auto increment of the ID of an input, and then assign the ID to be the for attribute for the associated label

Here is the code :

```
function addIDRowBuilder() {
    var i = 0;
    $('.form-control').each(function () {
        i++;

        var newID = 'form-control' + i;
        $(this).attr('id', newID);
        $(this).attr('name', newID);

        var testClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];

        $(this).parent().find('.label-for-' + testClass).attr('for', newID);
        $(this).parent().find('.label-for-sql-filter-connector' + testClass).attr('for', newID);

    });
}
```

It is not however assigning the for attribute to the label for the input that is disabled.
Here is the code on where it's being produced. The rows of these are being duplicated, which is the reason for given them auto incremented ID's.

```
        string filterLabel = "<label class=\"label-for-sql-filter-select sr-only\">Filter</label>";
        string filterField = "<select class=\"form-control sql-filter-select\"></select>";
        string criteriaLabel = "<label class=\"label-for-sql-filter-criteria sr-only\">Criteria</label>";
        string filterCriteria = "<select class=\"form-control sql-filter-criteria\">" + _query_builder_funcs1.GstrFilterList + "</select>";
        string inputLabel = "<label class=\"label-for-input-access sr-only\">Input</label>";
        string inputBox = "<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control input-access\"></input>";
        string addButton = "<a class=\"btn btn-success\" onclick=\"addQueryBuilderRow(this);\"><i class=\"fas fa-plus\"></i></a>";
        string removeButton = "<a class=\"btn btn-danger hidden\" onclick=\"removeQueryBuilderRow(this);\"><i class=\"fas fa-times\"></i></a>";
        string connectorLabel = "<label class=\"label-for-sql-filter-connector sr-only\">Connector</label>";
        string connectorDropbox = "<select class=\"hidden form-control sql-filter-connector\" disabled>" + _query_builder_funcs1.GStrKPIConnectorList + "</select>";
```

The disabled input is being assigned the ID and Name but the label for it is not. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out an answer by tidying up the jQuery code.

```
function addIDRowBuilder() {
    var i = 0;
    $('.form-control').each(function () {
        i++;

        var newID = $(this).attr('id');


        if (newID == "" || newID == undefined) {
            newID = 'form-control' + i;
        }

        $(this).attr('id', newID);
        $(this).attr('name', newID);

        $(this).prev().attr('for', newID);

    });
}
```

It is assigning the 'for' to the previous attribute, which in this case is the labels for the inputs with the class of form-control. 
The way I did it before was very restrictive.